# Adding JPA support to Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am trying to generate JSF Pages From Entity Classes in Netbeans and I get the error

> Cannot be generated for Java EE 6 sources without server with complete
>  Java EE 6 Web Profile support (at least EJB Lite support).

I've tried adding the Full JEE Web Profile JAR (javaee-web-api-7.0.jar) but still refuses.

Comment: Netbeans is right. Tomcat is not a Java EE server in first place. Get a normal Java EE server.

Comment: Is there no way to hack this to work in Tomcat? JSF works fine but I want JPA as well. It works fine on Glassfish but it is expensive to host Apps on a Glassfish server so I am switching to Tomcat.